# difficulty in installing SciPy and Numpy in Ubuntu(9.04)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

HI folks.
    I have difficulty in installing these items in Ubuntu.......plz help me as soon as possible.iam experiencing errors such as no module name found......sometimes certain libraries are not found.......plz folks can all of u state the basic libraries required for installing these items and where to find them

Comment: You should provide us with more details...what kind of error? none of us here is a phsycic, well at least I am not :D

Comment: "Clairvoyant interface is down - please try again later."

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question as stands is being voted to close and the reason is it is very unspecific - we can't answer it in its current form. We can't see what errors you're experiencing and why it doesn't work - there are a multitude of possible reasons. If you make your question more specific, we'll be able to help.

Comment: I should add you *can* edit your questions. There is no need to post a new one, just click the edit box and provide us with some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start at the beginning - do you have Python installed and running on Ubuntu?  If not, you won't have NumPy or SciPy, either.

Did you download NumPy and SciPy and unpack them to your hard drive?  Do you see directories that contain setup.py somewhere?

Usually it's `python setup.py install` in a command shell to install modules like NumPy and SciPy.  See if that works for you.

Comment: nope it doesn't work bcoz iam getting an error no module found

Answer (score 1):

There are [Numpy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python/python-numpy) and SciPy packages already in the Ubuntu repositories (SciPy is in the universe repo, you will have to enable this). No need to compile anything. You didn't state your Ubuntu version, so the links show the versions for Ubuntu Lucid (10.04LTS).

ps: Sorry, only one link allowed. But you see the pattern. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple and convenient way to install numpy, scipy, and many other tools for scientific programming, you should give a look at [Python(x,y)](http://www.pythonxy.com/).